# A simple OData routing in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I followed the tutorial [Creating an Odata end-point](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/creating-an-odata-endpoint)

and created a ODataController like so:

```
public class StudentSetController : ODataController
{
    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<StudentRef> GetAllStudents([FromODataUri] string StudentId)
    {
            long Student= Convert.ToInt64(Student);
            return (from b in new OStudentContext(StudentId).StudentRef select b).AsQueryable();            

    }

    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<StudentRef> GetAllStudentCategories([FromODataUri] string StudentId, string courseId)
    {
        long lStudentId= Convert.ToInt64(StudentId);
        long lcourseId= Convert.ToInt64(courseId);
        return (from b in new OStudentCategoryContext(lStudentId, lcourseId).StudentRef select b).AsQueryable();

    }
}
```

Here's the code in WebApiConfig:

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<StudentRef>("StudentSet");

config.Routes.MapODataRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel()
```

The first method works with this URL

```
http://localhost:32944/odata/StudentSet?StudentId=40
```

How do I configure it to work like so:

```
http://localhost:32944/odata/StudentSet/AllStudents?StudentId=40
```

Also how do I configure to access GetAllStudentCategories method?

Thanks in advance.